# Add text prompts when app is first invoked on each day?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, timestamp

What do I need to do in my monotouch app to programmatically add daily prompts or reminders through the device when the app is first invoked ON EACH DAY?

One option that seems ineffective though is to create and save a temp file for each day. Everytime the app is loaded it checks whether there exist a file for that day, if not create a new one and generate the prompt, else skip, e.g. as below

```
string temp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(temp))
{
     System.IO.File.Create(temp);
     // generate prompt
}
```

Just seems messy - any better way of doing this?

Comment: chiffre - edited my original post...

Comment: Are you open to an Objective-C method inside your AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your approach works - but you likely do not want to create a new file each day. It would be best to use a single file and look at it's timestamp.

Also note that Apple recently started checking applications that saves data (in `Documents`) on startup (i.e. it's not user initiated and gets synced to backups / iCloud). That could be important if your application is targeting the AppStore.

Beside files you can look at `NSUserDefaults` to save your "last used date". See the "[Working with the File System](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_the_File_System)" article on Xamarin's web site for more details (and other options).